# Converting a list into a string and removing specific characters in string

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove the vowels in my block of code. However, I'm getting an error I do not understand. What am I doing wrong?

```
def remove_vowel(list):
  for num in range(0,len(list)):
    try: 
      list.remove('a','e','i','o','u')
    except: 
          new_str = ''.list.join(list)
          return newstr
remove_vowel(['p','e','o','p','l','e'])
```

Edit: The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                               
  File "remove_vowel.py", line 10, in <module>                                                   
    print(remove_vowel(['p','e','o','p','l','e']))                                               
  File "remove_vowel.py", line 8, in remove_vowel                                                
    new_str = ''.list.join(list)                                                                 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'list'
```

Comment: It is hard for others to help with your error when you don't say what it is

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: Several of the things you're doing don't work the way you think they do. I recommend spending some time with the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Comment: I apologize for the vague question, I will defintely be more descriptive in the future initially. I do however apperciate everyone's help. I am only 4 days into learning Python and it's still a grueling learning process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the error you are getting is that `remove()` takes only one argument. Example -

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l.remove(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: remove() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

The second issue is there is nothing like - `''.list` - str does not have a `list` attribute.

That is why you cannot do something like -

```
list.remove('a','e','i','o','u')
```

A easy way to do what you want would be to use a new list , that does not have any vowels. Example -

```
def remove_vowel(l):
    return ''.join([x for x in l if x.lower() not in ['a','e','i','o','u']])
```

I am returning the joined string, since that is what you seem to be returning as well.

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def remove_vowel(l):
...     return ''.join([x for x in l if x.lower() not in ['a','e','i','o','u']])
...
>>> remove_vowel(['p','e','o','p','l','e'])
'ppl'
```

Comment: I have, unfortunely I do not have enough reputation for it view publicly.

Comment: You do not need reputation for accepting answers, click on the tick mark on the left side for it

Comment: @Rainmaker Check here - [How does accepting answers work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) - for more details.